# big O with different orders

Tags: asymptotics

I'm trying to show the following and I'm not quite sure how:

> $f_1(n) = n^n$ is $O(f_2(n) = 3^{2^n})$ and $f_2(n) = 3^{2^n} = O(f_3(n) = 2^{3^n}) $

does anyone have an idea? calculating the limits is an option it's just that I don't get too far that way either.
thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first,
it is enough to show that
$\dfrac{n^n}{2^{3^n}}
\lt c$
for some $c > 0$
for all large enough $n$.
Since
$\dfrac{n^n}{2^{3^n}}
\to 0$,
this is more than enough.

For the second,
when there are complicated exponents,
I take logs.
This makes
$f_2(n) = 3^{2^n} = O(f_3(n) = 2^{3^n})
$
become
$\ln f_2(n)
=2^n \ln 3
$
and
$\ln f_3(n)
=3^n \ln 2
$
and clearly
$\ln f_3(n)
$
is a lot larger.

Comment: How can you show the first limit?

Comment: Take logs. Note that if $\ln f(n)/\ln g(n) \to 0$ and $f(n), g(n) \to \infty$ then $f(n)/g(n) \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your help